# Using Selenium to click a input type submit button

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, input, click, submit

Trying to click this

```
<input type="submit" value="Log In" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block">
```

I have tried

```
driver.find_element("class", "btn").click()

driver.find_element("class", "btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block").click()

driver.find_element("value", "Log In").click()
```

But all give error

```
InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: invalid locator
```

How can I click on this?

EDIT:

now ive tried

```
driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block").click()
```

but get error

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using "By"

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

And you can select your element it in different ways:

By Class:

```
driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block").click()
```

By XPATH:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//input[@value="Log In"]').click()
```

By CSS selector:

```
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input.btn.btn-lg.btn-primary.btn-block').click()
```

reference: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html

Comment: That last one "By CSS selector" works! Thank you